# Trying to insert logo into header of a Word document I'm creating from an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to insert logo on the left side of a header in a Word document, I'm creating from Excel.

Code

```
Sub CreateWordFileFromExcel()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim filePath As String
             
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    desktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    filePath = desktopPath & "TemplateMEMO.docx"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").UsedRange.Copy

    Dim headerRange As Object
    Set headerRange = wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range

    wordDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    headerRange.Text = "Compay name" & vbCr & _
                  "Street" & vbCr & _
                  "City" & vbCr & _
                  "Country" & vbCr & _
                  "Tel: *digits*" & vbCr & _
                  "Fax: *digits*" & vbCr & _
                  "company-website"
    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
    headerRange.Font.Size = 9
    wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("A1:D6").Copy
    wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Paste

    Dim logoShape As Object
    Set logoShape = wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Count)
     
    logoShape.Left = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the left margin
    logoShape.Top = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the top margin
    logoShape.Height = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
    logoShape.Width = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False

    wordDoc.SaveAs filePath

    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set headerRange = Nothing
    Set logoShape = Nothing
End Sub
```

Attached is how sheet 3 looks like

[How sheet 3 look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jPwE.png)

I copy pasted logo from a Word file. I need it to be on left side of each page in a Word document

I tried this

```
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("A1:D6").Copy
      wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Paste

      Dim logoShape As Object
      Set logoShape = wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Count)
      logoShape.Left = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the left margin
      logoShape.Top = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the top margin
      logoShape.Height = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
      logoShape.Width = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
```

Comment: Can I suggest you check out the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it gives you hints on how to ask good questions and also notes about accepting answers (you might find you get more help for subsequent questions if you accept answers to previous questions). Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then update your question.